# How to print 3600.125 seconds in "H:M:S.s" format in Julia

Tags: time, julia

I got some time intervals using the `tic()` and `toc()` functions which are in seconds. 
Let's suppose I have a time interval `dt=3600.125` seconds. How can I print it in "H:M:S.s" format using Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own function. The main function to know is `divrem` which gives you the divisor as well as the remainder in one convenient function call.

```
dt=3600.125 

function hmss(dt)
    (h,r) = divrem(dt,60*60)
    (m,r) = divrem(r, 60)
    #(s,r) = divrem(r, 60)
    string(Int(h),":",Int(m),":",r)
end

hmss(dt)

hmss(3452.98)
```

Comment: Why would you do that when Julia's DateTime support is so good as it is?

Comment: because teaching how is more important than what. ppl who leanr my method can move to native datetime but other around is harder

Comment: Also because using DateTime in this case is cumbersome. It requires calling some functions, formatting and some tricks. See e.g. Liso's answer below, for example. Solution from xiaodai is short and simple.

Answer (score 4):

If you convert it to Dates formats then you can use [this method](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-get-dates-period-without-label/6718/8?u=daneel).

```
julia> t1 = now()
2017-11-10T10:00:51.974
# Wait
julia> t2 = now()
2017-11-10T10:10:07.895
julia> x = Dates.canonicalize(Dates.CompoundPeriod(t2-t1))
9 minutes, 15 seconds, 921 milliseconds

julia> x.periods
3-element Array{Base.Dates.Period,1}:
 9 minutes      
 15 seconds      
 921 milliseconds

julia> x.periods[2]
15 seconds

julia> x.periods[2].value
18
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [dates section in the manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/dates).

Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but this works for instance:

```
julia> Dates.format(DateTime("2017-10-01T01:02:03"), "H:M:S.s")
"1:2:3.0"
```

Comment: Yes! I'd strongly recommend using the powerful inbuilt facilities for DateTime manipulation in Julia.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard could you look at my answer and probably get better use of "inbuilt facilities"? From my point of view it is still a little complicated in Julia. For example I would expect that `Dates.format(Dates.Nanosecond(1e8), dateformat"S.s")` could be working.

Comment: This aswer solves the problem for periods less than 3600*24 seconds. However a fake date is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
""" working properly only if 0<= sec <=86400 otherwise truncating """
function fmtsec(sec, fmt::Dates.DateFormat)
    # nanos = Dates.Nanosecond(sec * 1e9)  # we could get InexactError here!
    nanos = Dates.Nanosecond(trunc(Int, sec * 1e9))
    mytime = Dates.Time(nanos)
    Dates.format(mytime, fmt)
end

fmt = dateformat"H:M:S.s"  # Creating a DateFormat object is expensive. (see doc)

fmtsec(3600.125, fmt)  # "1:0:0.125"
```

EDIT: Without truncating nanoseconds we could get error ->

```
julia> tic();sleep(1);old_fmtsec(toc(), dateformat"S.s")
elapsed time: 1.002896514 seconds
ERROR: InexactError()
Stacktrace:
 [1] convert(::Type{Int64}, ::Float64) at ./float.jl:679
 [2] fmtsec(::Float64, ::DateFormat{Symbol("S.s"),Tuple{Base.Dates.DatePart{'S'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'s'}}}) at ./REPL[47]:2

julia> tic();sleep(1);old_fmtsec(toc(), dateformat"S.s")
elapsed time: 1.002857122 seconds
"1.002"
```

`tic` & `toc` are deprecated. `toc` could bring rounding error because it internally use time_ns but nanoseconds convert to seconds dividing by 1e9.

Comment: Similar approach in one line `using Dates; toStringTime(seconds,template="H:M:S.s") =  Dates.format(Time(0) + Millisecond(round(seconds*1000)),template)`

Answer (score 0):

This date from `toc()` and `time()` in Julia uses `UNIX timestamp`, i.e., seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970

The same occurs with the function `ctime(f)` that returns timestamp from a file path `f`.

The conversion is very straightforward.

```
tic()
....
dif = toc()
# My local is Brazil, one should replace for its local format
Dt = DateTime(LibC.strftime(dif),"d/m/y H:M:S")
```

`LibC` does not have to be imported explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I had a go now, but doing the carry over is a bit messy sorry:

```
using Dates
using Printf

function formatDuration(duration::Period, types::Vector{DataType}=[Hour, Minute, Second]; addUnit::Bool=false)
    periods = canonicalize(Dates.CompoundPeriod(duration)).periods

    missingTypes = Vector{DataType}(types)

    newPeriods = vcat(periods, map(t->t(0), missingTypes))
    sort!(newPeriods; rev=true)
    newPeriods1 = Vector{Period}()

    carryover = nothing
    for (i, p) in enumerate(newPeriods)
        typeofp = typeof(p)
        if !isnothing(carryover)
            newPeriod = convert(typeofp, floor(Millisecond(p) + Millisecond(carryover), typeofp(1)))
            carryover = nothing
        else
            newPeriod = p
        end
        if (typeof(newPeriod) in types)
            push!(newPeriods1, newPeriod)
            filter!(e->e≠typeofp,missingTypes)
        else
            carryover = newPeriod
        end
    end
    m = map(types) do t
        f = findfirst(x -> typeof(x) == t, newPeriods1);
        r = isnothing(f) ? 0 : newPeriods1[f].value;
        @sprintf("%02d",r) * (addUnit ? lowercase("$t"[1]) : "")
    end
    join(m, ":")
end
```

Usage examples:

```
@show formatDuration(Millisecond(3600.125*1000))
# returns "01:00:00"
@show formatDuration(Day(2), [Hour, Minute, Second])
# returns "48:00:00"
@show formatDuration(Second(100000000), [Hour, Minute, Second])
# returns "27777:46:40"
@show formatDuration(Second(100000001), [Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond])
# returns "1157:09:46:41:00"
@show formatDuration(Millisecond(10000000001), 
    [Week, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond]; addUnit=true)
#returns "16w:03d:17h:46m:40s:01m"
```